# melonJS: Entity and solid block on collision layer

Tags: collision-detection, javascript

Actually I have my player entity with 64x64 sprite animation and 18x60 hitbox also the map is made by 16x16 tiles.
When my player goes some way he can pass through blocks (but not all of them).
For example there are 4 situations:

**Good** *(player can't pass the tile with isSolid property on collision layer)*

[image]

**Good** *(player can't pass the tile with isSolid property on collision layer)*

[image]

**Bad** *(player pass the tile with isSolid property on collision layer)*

[image]

**Bad** *(player pass the tile with isSolid property on collision layer)*

[image]

Looks like [melonJS](http://www.melonjs.org/) checks only corners of hitbox instead of whole rectangle.
Can anyone help me in this situation.

**UPD:** my PlayerEntity.

```
var PlayerEntity = me.ObjectEntity.extend({
    init: function(x, y, settings) {
            settings.image = "player";
            settings.spritewidth = 64;
            settings.spriteheight = 64;
            this.parent(x, y, settings);
            this.setVelocity(3, 10);
            this.updateColRect(23, 18, 4, 60);
            me.game.viewport.follow(this.pos, me.game.viewport.AXIS.BOTH);
            this.direction = 'stand2';
            this.addAnimation("run", [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]);
            this.addAnimation("stand", [33]);
            this.addAnimation("stand2", [44]);
            this.addAnimation("jump", [29,29,29,29,29,29,29,29,27,27]);
            this.addAnimation("jump2", [26,27,27,27,29,29,27,27,26]);
    },
    update: function() {
            hadSpeed = this.vel.y != 0 || this.vel.x != 0 ;
            if(hadSpeed)
                this.animationspeed = me.sys.fps / 10;

            if (me.input.isKeyPressed('left')) {
                this.jumping ? this.setCurrentAnimation('jump2') : this.setCurrentAnimation('run');
                this.flipX(false);
                this.vel.x = -this.accel.x * me.timer.tick;
                this.direction = 'left';
            }
            ...
            right/jump etc goes here
            ...
            updated = this.updateMovement();
            if (!hadSpeed) this.setCurrentAnimation('stand');
            if (updated) this.parent(this);
            return updated;
    }
});
```

Comment: Looking in the source code for MelonJS it appears that it does perform a proper bounding box collision check. http://www.melonjs.org/build/melonJS-0.9.4.js search for `overlaps : function(r)`. Are you sure you marked the boxes as collide and not platform? Does onCollision get triggered on the sprite? Post your relevant code, the bug is most likely in your code or level, not in the framework.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I take the code from [official tutorial](http://www.melonjs.org/tutorial/index.html). Anyway I made an update of my question.

Comment: Add `onCollision: function() {alert("collided")}` and see if it gets triggered, and from what I saw you can mark blocks as platforms or solid, platform would allow you to enter them from the side or below and cause the problem.

Comment: I added your line of code to my `PlayerEntity` but it never triggered. Also all my blocks have `isSolid` flag. I have no chance to change framwork code so I need somehow to ovveride `checkCollision` method (with proper logic) in my `PlayerEntity`. Also I found that it is an general [bug](https://github.com/obiot/melonJS/issues/50) for [melonJs](http://www.melonjs.org/)